# TBB do i have to destroy child task or is parent taking care?

Tags: c++, tbb

When the parent is destroyed, will the childs be automatically destroyed as well or do i have to do destroy them explicitly?

```
tbb::task *parent = new(tbb::task::allocate_root()) tbb::empty_task;
parent->increment_ref_count();

for (...){
    new(parent->allocate_child()) aSampleTask(this);
    parent->increment_ref_count();
    parent->spawn(*save);
}
parent->wait_for_all();
tbb::task::destroy(*parent);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Usually, a task is automatically destroyed by the scheduler after its method execute returns. But sometimes task objects are used idiomatically (such as for reference counting) without ever running  execute. Such tasks should be disposed with method destroy.
>   [Explicit task Destruction](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/hh_goto.htm?index.htm#reference/task_scheduler/explicit_task_destruction.html)

Also you should use `static void spawn( task& t )` [task Class](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/index.htm#reference/task_scheduler/task_cls.html) (see Notes)

BTW, do you really need to use tasks? TBB provides various parallel [algorithms](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/index.htm#reference/algorithms.html)

Comment: `spawn()` is fine, static functions can be referenced like this, through pointers to class instance. Especially, it used to be non-static method and old codes still work with new static method approach.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you don't need destroy the child tasks explicitly, since they don't have any further children. I also checked the source code, and the following comments.

> //! Destroy a task.
>
> /** Usually, calling this method is unnecessary, because a task is implicitly deleted after its execute() method runs.  However, sometimes a task needs to be explicitly deallocated, such as when a root task is used as the parent in spawn_and_wait_for_all. */
>
> static void __TBB_EXPORTED_FUNC destroy( task& victim );